# default directory must be absolute

Tags: java, linux

My code calls the methods in the log4j package:

```
org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties")
```

There is no problem running on Windows system and Linux virtual machine. However, when running on a Linux virtual machine provided by the company, the following error occurs, as following picture shows:

[image]

Where do I start to resolve it?

Supplement:
this is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(configDir + File.separator + "log4j.properties");
    if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("load complete：" + configDir + File.separator + "log4j.properties");
    }
}
```

The first line of execution reports an error, error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
...
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:315)
    at com.dcits.provider.BaffleProvider.main(BaffleProvider.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: default directory must be absolute
...
```

Comment: Can you provide some code so the community can help better? Thanks!

Comment: What is the current working directory when you start your program?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question

Comment: wait a moment, I'm looking to see if there's a JDK version issue that I compiled using 1.8 but ran on 1.7

Comment: It's not a compilation problem, it's probably a machine environment variable problem. I'll ask the operations staff

Comment: The same exception appears when there is no permission to work with the working directory for the user which runs the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

The default FileSystem can not be constructed when the user directory system property (i.e `"user.dir"`), is NOT an absolute path.

Executing this code in Java 8 on both Windows and AIX generates runtime exceptions similar to that seen by the original poster.

```
public class RelativeUserDir
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Set the "user.dir" property to the "current directory" relative path
        System.setProperty("user.dir", ".");

        FileSystems.getDefault();
    }
}
```

**Windows:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Default directory is not an absolute path
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.<init>(WindowsFileSystem.java:61)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.<init>(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:53)
    at sun.nio.fs.DefaultFileSystemProvider.create(DefaultFileSystemProvider.java:36)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.getDefaultProvider(FileSystems.java:108)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.access$000(FileSystems.java:89)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder$1.run(FileSystems.java:98)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder$1.run(FileSystems.java:96)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.defaultFileSystem(FileSystems.java:96)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.<clinit>(FileSystems.java:90)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault(FileSystems.java:176)
    at RelativeUserDir.main(RelativeUserDir.java:12)
```

**AIX:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:146)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:135)
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault(FileSystems.java:187)
        at RelativeUserDir.main(RelativeUserDir.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: default directory must be absolute
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.<init>(UnixFileSystem.java:67)
        at sun.nio.fs.AixFileSystem.<init>(AixFileSystem.java:55)
        at sun.nio.fs.AixFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(AixFileSystemProvider.java:62)
        at sun.nio.fs.AixFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(AixFileSystemProvider.java:55)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.<init>(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:68)
        at sun.nio.fs.AixFileSystemProvider.<init>(AixFileSystemProvider.java:57)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1773)
        at sun.nio.fs.DefaultFileSystemProvider.createProvider(DefaultFileSystemProvider.java:60)
        at sun.nio.fs.DefaultFileSystemProvider.create(DefaultFileSystemProvider.java:78)
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.getDefaultProvider(FileSystems.java:119)
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.access$000(FileSystems.java:100)
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder$1.run(FileSystems.java:109)
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder$1.run(FileSystems.java:107)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:638)
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.defaultFileSystem(FileSystems.java:107)
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.<clinit>(FileSystems.java:101)
        ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 1):

When encountering this problem, especially when running under jdk1.7, notice whether the 'user.dir' environment variable has been changed or set. The problem I encountered is that the 'user.dir' was wrongly set by me